# iterating over an array of class objects using ngFor not displaying in angular 5

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ngfor

I am trying to iterate over an array of class objects for a dropdown menu in Angular 5. Nothing is displaying in the dropdown menu and there are no errors in the browser console.

The object array is derived from this model:

```
    export class NewEnglandState {
    constructor (
        name: string,
        abbrv: string,
        lat: number,
        lng: number,
        zoom: number,
    ) {}
}
```

In the component I built the array:

```
    export class InterfaceComponent implements OnInit {
      newenglandstates = [
        new NewEnglandState('Massachusetts', 'MA', 42.02889443064134, -71.65008582421876, 8 ),
        new NewEnglandState( 'Connecticut', 'CT', 41.527086145800006, -72.65808142968751, 9 ),
        new NewEnglandState( 'Maine', 'ME', 44.95702443907399, -68.95843543359376, 7 ),
        new NewEnglandState( 'New Hampshire', 'NH', 43.95328236137632, -71.28753699609376, 8 ),
        new NewEnglandState('Rhode Island', 'RI', 41.64828864411775, -71.30401648828126, 9 ),
        new NewEnglandState('Vermont', 'VT', 43.901850824945996, -72.50152625390626, 8 ),
        new NewEnglandState('All New England', 'ANE', 43.8992496, -71.6135105, 7 )
      ];
}
```

This is what I have in the component's HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" title="Filter by state."  (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)">
            <option *ngFor="let state of newenglandstates" value="state.abbrv">
                {{ state.name }}
            </option>           
        </select>
```

No text is displaying in the dropdown menu. Is there something I need to add to the ngFor function?

Comment: are there any error messages logging to the console?

Comment: There's no error messages

Comment: you are not setting the properties on your constructor... use this.name = name or decorate the constructor parameter with public keyword

Comment: For automatic property setting, they need an access modifier

Comment: For example: `constructor(public name: string, public abbrv: string, ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems with your code

**Problem 1:**

```
<option *ngFor="let state of newenglandstates" value="state.abbrv">
    {{ state.name }}
</option>
```

should be

```
<option *ngFor="let state of newenglandstates" value="{{state.abbrv}}">
   {{ state.name }}
</option>
```

`value` is used as a HTML attribute and expects a string value, so when `value="state.abbrv"`, all the options end up having the string `state.abbrv` (not the value of `state.abbrv`), hence you need to use the data binding syntax to provide the value instead.

**Problem 2:**

Your class constructor should be

```
export class NewEnglandState {
    constructor (
        public name: string,
        public abbrv: string,
        public lat: number,
        public lng: number,
        public zoom: number,
    ) {}
}
```

which is equivalent to

```
export class NewEnglandState {

  public name: string;
  public abbrv: string;
  public lat: number;
  public lng: number;
  public zoom: number;

  constructor(
    name: string,
    abbrv: string,
    lat: number,
    lng: number,
    zoom: number,
  ) {
    this.name = name;
    this.abbrv = abbrv;
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lng = lng;
    this.zoom = zoom;
  }
}
```

missing the `public` keyword (or any access specifier in general) in the constructor parameter makes the parameters plain function arguments.

[working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-1290)

Comment: Adding the public keyword to the constructor parameters solved it. Thanks.